# open form with crystalreportsviewer using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on one application. in datagridview I have created event `dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick` which would supposed to open another form that has `crystalreportviewer component`, then pass the path of the crystalreportdocument to the crystalreportviewer and load that report so it can present data...

so far I have done this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //string that carries path of the report document
        string path = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ReportPath"].Value.ToString();

    }
```

Form3 looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ICAMReports
{
   public partial class Form3 : Form
   {
        public Form3(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
   }
}
```

Form3.Designer looks like:

```
namespace ICAMReports
{
     partial class Form3
     {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        this.crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // crystalReportViewer1
        // 
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Name = "crystalReportViewer1";
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(609, 413);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(609, 413);
        this.Controls.Add(this.crystalReportViewer1);
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.Text = "Form3";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ReportPath"].Value.ToString();
        Form3 form = new Form3(path);
        //ReportDocument crystal = new ReportDocument();
        //crystal.Load(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ReportPath"].Value.ToString());
        //pass = crystal;
        form.Show();
    }
```

Form3.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ICAMReports
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public string source;
        public Form3(string path)
        {
            source = path;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = source;
        }
    }
}
```

Form3.Designer.cs

```
namespace ICAMReports
{
    partial class Form3
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // crystalReportViewer1
        // 
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Name = "crystalReportViewer1";
        this.crystalReportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(609, 413);
        this.crystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(609, 413);
        this.Controls.Add(this.crystalReportViewer1);
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.Text = "Form3";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1;
}
}
```

Comment: no problem m8. Since I'm junior/intermediate level developer and I understand how this can be: sometimes partial code doesn't get enough information to understand how things work, so instead posting partial, I've added complete code to make it easier for the rest of folks.

cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new form in your project. Then in that form's code you change the constructor to take a string argument that is the report path.

The code you then use to show that form is:

```
//CrystalReportForm is your new form.
CrystalReportForm form = new CrystalReportForm(path); 
form.Show(); //or form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: not sure that I understood you very well, I have event that needs to pass variable (crystal document path), and from that I need to open another form (obviously that is the part) Form3 form = new Form(); form.Show(); but in that form3 I need to load crystalreportviewer and pass the path of crystalreport document so the viewer can open the report...

Comment: From what I understood you have the crystal report viewer component in that form already? So the only thing you need is the path? In that case, change the constructor for Form3 to include a string parameter that you can use to get the path that the crystal report viewer will load.

Comment: Yes, Form have crystalReportViewer1 component: after I created Form, I added by drag-drop crystalreportviewer component... I have added additional code to see what I've done so far...